# Magento PHP Extension intl missing in Ubuntu 16

Tags: php, magento2

Am using `Ubuntu 16.04.1` and `PHP 7.0.22`, When i try to install `Magento 2.2.3` the below php extension missing error.

- PHP Extension intl.
- PHP Extension zip.

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: So have you tried to install those extensions into you PHP?

Comment: Yes but i had this `Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?` response

Comment: Might be better to ask this on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/795629/install-php-extensions-in-ubuntu-16-04) heres a starter for 10

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks for your response..

Comment: Edit your php.ini file and un-comment or add below extensions

 

extension=php_intl.dll

extension=php-zip.dll

 

Also check if these .dll files are present under "/php/ext" folder. If not you need to install them and keep these files under "ext" folder. 

 

Restart your PHP services and try to reinstall. The error will be resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
1.sudo apt-get update

2.sudo apt-get install php7.0-intl
```

and Then if you get the error

```
3.sudo apt-get install -f
```